# Nautilus after choosing Copy/Move to... Open tabs not shown on the Destination window

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus

Nautilus 3.14.x Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has had a function to offer the open tabs for the copy/move files destination on the side pane, the paths are automatically added by its own. But 18/20.04 LTS doesn't offer the same thing, nautilus 3.3x.x.

It is not an end of the world or any serious issues. And I am missing it badly.

How can I bring back the **Open Tab** directories into the new Nautilus?

**Nautilus 3.14.3**
[image]

**Nautilus 3.36.3**
[image: nautilus3.36.3]

In both cases, I open the directory *Dict* beforehand start moving files by "Move to...".